# Using procmail to copy emails to another address and altering "from"

Tags: email, procmail

I get email alerts that are generated by a user on one of my servers. These alerts are generated by server@######.com and they have to do with third party software not working properly.

I'm trying to use procmail to copy (as I want to keep receiving these) these emails to ABC@XYZ.com.

I'm looking for emails that, in their body, have "C:" followed by 6 characters, a dot, and 3 more characters. All of that is working fine, but I want the third party to get these emails from me bruno@XXXXXX.com rather than server.

How can I copy the email to a third party AND change the from address to be bruno@XXXXX.com?

Here's the procmail file:

```
cat .procmailrc
DROPPRIVS=yes
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log

:0 c:
* B ?? C:......\....
! ABC@XYZ.com

:0 B:
* ^To: .*alerts@XXXXXX.com
! bruno@XXXXXX.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the headers you want with [`formail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/formail) before piping to `sendmail`. (Recall that `!` is basically a shorthand for `| $SENDMAIL $SENDMAILFLAGS`.)

Do I understand correctly that the first recipe is the one you would like to modify?

```
:0 c  # No lockfile when forwarding
* B ?? C:......\....
| formail -I 'From: bruno@XXXXXX.com' \
  | $SENDMAIL $SENDMAILFLAGS ABC@XYZ.com
```

Your second recipe similarly should not have a lock file; see http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking

Comment: This answer is basically covered by http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#forward-mod

Comment: Also not sure why you have a `B` flag on the second recipe; do you really want to examine the message body for a match on that regex?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, it's the first recipe that I'd like to modify. And the second one, yes, I want to check the body for a specific string. I must have left that part out of the second recipe when creating this question.